# how to set firefox profile on selenium driver linux python

Tags: python, selenium

Im looking for a little help to have selenium use my profile for firefox

I have found my firefox profile file location: /root/.mozilla/firefox/abcdefgh.default

```
import time
import random
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

with open("proxylist.txt") as f: 
     proxy_list = f.read().splitlines()
proxy_ip, proxy_port = random.choice(proxy_list).split(":")

profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", proxy_ip)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(proxy_port))
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(firefox_profile=profile)
driver.get("https://www.ipleak.net")
time.sleep(60)
driver.close()
```

Comment: Without some sample code, it's impossible to know what library are you using or how are you calling it

Comment: @memoselyk I added my code if you could help thanks

Comment: @memoselyk at the moment im not calling it at all. I am not sure how to. Right now this is just what my code is without any errors. Id like to point selenium to use my iceweasel browsers but the only way i could make it work was with just the firefox driver. Id really like to point it to my real browser to use. Or 2ndly to use one of my user profiles on iceweasel or firefox (as i also downloaded browser). My OS is Kali 2.0, I tried useing my windows machine but had alot more difficulties.

Answer (score 4):

From the documentation of `webdriver.FirefoxProfile`:

> :args:
>
> profile_directory: Directory of profile that you want to use.
>      This defaults to None and will create a new
>      directory when object is created.

So, the following **should** work:

```
profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/root/.mozilla/firefox/abcdefgh.default')
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
```

Comment: Wow thanks mate lol something so simple takes me so long to figure out. Best luck and wishes

Comment: If this solved your problem, please [accept](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) the answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
import time
import random
import requests
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()

with open("proxylist.txt") as f: 
     proxy_list = f.read().splitlines()
proxy_ip, proxy_port = random.choice(proxy_list).split(":")

profile.set_preference("network.proxy.type", 1)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http", proxy_ip)
profile.set_preference("network.proxy.http_port", int(proxy_port))
profile.update_preferences()
driver = webdriver.Firefox(profile)
driver.get("https://www.ipleak.net")
time.sleep(60)
driver.close()
```