# Managing Chrome policies via Selenium Webdriver

Tags: google-chrome, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

Is there a way to modify policy settings for Chrome instances in a way that remote ChromeDriver on Selenium Grid would understand? Modifying the registry on a Selenium Node would probably work, but could I pass the required settings through Selenium server somehow?

`https://www.chromium.org/administrators/policy-list-3#AutoSelectCertificateForUrls`

Comment: easiest way is to use existing browser profile; many people don't realize selenium is using a temporary browser profile with default settings. With existing profile is possible to run tests with almost any browser customization. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562675/selenium-chromedriver-open-chrome-normally/50568965#50568965

Comment: @pburgr it is sadly not that straightforward when using Chromedriver

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not solve the problem of setting Chrome policies, but the broader problem of selecting client SSL certificate during execution of Selenium tests has been solved by setting up a proxy with Mitm capabilities, such as https://github.com/mrog/LittleProxy, making the original issue void.