# Selenium Webdriver Login activity on Amazon.com: “Verification needed”

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to run some automated tests on amazon.com by using Selenium Webdriver. I tried to log in to the system but after entering the password, system either directs to “Verification needed” page and says “We will email you a code to verify your identity. This is required when something about your sign-in activity changes, like signing in from a new device or location.”

or directs to “wrong password or email” page (eventhough I try correct account information).

So my question is: How can I handle that two factor authentication in my test script?

Note: I am using ChromeDriver and Java

Comment: using selenium: open email account, find the email with link, click on link. Email is not any different than other web pages

Comment: You could also work with an email API. If using gmail, google has a decent api for both Java and Python: https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are two possible approaches:

first one, you can as Kiril S mentioned, get the link from email (mailinator.com is fine inbox for such testing).

second approach is avoiding the second verification with existing browser profile. Selenium uses a temporary profile, that's probably the reason of the second verification. I'm using existing browser profile (firefox), see [Selenium Chromedriver - Open Chrome Normally](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562675/selenium-chromedriver-open-chrome-normally/50568965#50568965). For Chrome should be similar.