# In Selenium Webdriver with java, hot to click the "Get adobe Flash Player" icon?

Tags: selenium, flash, adobe

Every time I am running a script, the "Get adobe Flash Player" icon is being displayed, I already installed Adobe but anyway this icon is displayed and I cannot continue, I tried with xpath but is not working, could you give me an idea how to solve this please?
I tried these 2 ways but none is working:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@alt='Get Adobe Flash player'")).click();

driver.findElement(By.xpath("//img[@src='http://www.adobe.com/…/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif'")).click();
```

Thank you

Comment: Inspecting the icon shows this:   <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player">

Comment: could you add relevant html

Comment: Do you really need to click the icon? Or do you need to avoid even apearing the icon? Depending on the used browser, try to manualy create a new browser profile and use it for your tests. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50562675/selenium-chromedriver-open-chrome-normally/50568965#50568965. With existing browser profile, you need to install AFP just once, to the new profile.

Comment: If you have `installed Adobe but this icon is still displayed` you may require to add the settings in your _Browser Profile_

Comment: No no, if it weren't there it would be great, I just want to continue and display the login page.

Comment: See https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/30312/enable-flash-player-on-chrome-62-while-running-selenium-test